# External mics for AudioMoths

Tags: audiomoth

I've been using AudioMoths to record soundscapes at various sites, and then running those recordings through BirdNet to get an estimate of what bird species are present. I've been having some issues with the audio quality and tinkering around with the recording settings (e.g., gains, sampling frequency, etc.) didn't help.

I'd like to add an external mic to the AudioMoths; just wondering if anyone has experience with this, any suggestions about which mics work well or which to avoid, and any other tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Useful info here for building and attaching a microphone.
https://github.com/OpenAcousticDevices/Application-Notes/blob/master/Using_AudioMoth_with_External_Electret_Condenser_Microphones/Using_AudioMoth_with_External_Electret_Condenser_Microphones.pdf

You'll need some good wind protection if exposed.

Primo EM258 capsule has good Ultrasonic response for bat work as well.
PUI 5024 capsules are cheaper than Primo and work well for audible frequencies, I've had one running outside for a year with no problems.
Knowles SPU0410LR5H-QB Ultrasonic microphone can be made to work.
I think the limiting factor may be the quality that the Audiomoth can record at?

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 6):

Good question, there is definitely a possibility to do that by soldering a jack plug (ref:  SJ2-35464A-SMT-TR) on the audiomoth board. I've used it to plug in a hydrophone so I don't have any specific suggestions for microphones but the connector on the mic will need to be a 3.5mm jack or you'll need to use an adaptor.

Comment: Thanks for the plug reference; much appreciated. I'm used to working with hydrophones as well, so these terrestrial mics have me all confused

Answer (score 5):

Good info from Fuzzyface. I've used the Rugged Mount Mono Primo EM272 Microphone from micbooster.com with relatively good results. See here: https://micbooster.com/clippy-and-pluggy-microphones/113-rugged-mount-primo-em172-mono.html . I stuck an acoustic vent from micbooster directly on top of the capsule to give a little more waterproofness. See here: https://micbooster.com/microphone-holders/124-acoustic-microphone-vent.html#/69-protection-ipx4/124-pack-single
You can buy a windscreen from those folks too.
 I've just stuck my modified Audiomoth in a junction box from Amazon, drilled a hole and put the rugged mic on the bottom to shield from rain and water getting inside. My units survived rain and snow so I think it would probably work in most cases, but haven't tried it out in super wet regions.
Also if you don't want to solder and want to use different battery configurations (rechargable packs, D batteries, etc), or use the GPS feature (again without soldering) you could buy a Audiomoth Dev when they're back in stock at either Labmaker or Groupgets https://www.labmaker.org/collections/earth-and-ecology/products/audiomoth-dev . That way you can just plug in whatever you need including the audio jack.
[image: ARU in junction box with external mic]

Comment: Excellent info and follow-up from what FuzzyFace said. Much appreciated!